# React Native Android Files Do Not Exist

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a React Native App, and I got it to start on browser through Expo fine, but on Android, I get this error.

```
Unable to resolve module ./App.css from C:\Users\Gabe\Documents\React Native\MovieApp\App.js:

None of these files exist:
  * App.css(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  * App.css\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  1 | import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
  2 | //import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
> 3 | import './App.css';
```

I've made sure that I only have one `index.js`file, but otherwise I've never seen this before, and so I'm stumped.